# Javascript code not working in Visual Studio Express 2013 Preview for Windows

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, windows-8.1

So, This is my first Windows 8 app and I'm working on it using html/css and JS
I've developped it on a browser at first (I know, not a good habit) and I wanted to try it out on the Windows 8.1 app
Everything seemed to have slight glitches that I easily fixed, yet the javascript code didn't work at all, even though it worked perfectly on the browser.

Short story: the app enables you to make a countdown from 1h down, or 10mn down (for some purpose), it has two bottuns for each countdown: a start and a stop button.

I have no idea why, the cosole shows the following error: HTML1701

Here's the code:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var h, m, s, h1, m1, s1, output, output1, inter, inter1;

        //Preparing all the functions

        //facts' animation function

        function facts() {
            function solve() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#fun1").animate({ opacity: "0", }, 500, function () {
                        $("#fun2").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);
                    });
                }, 10500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#fun2").animate({ opacity: "0", }, 500, function () {
                        $("#fun3").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);
                    });
                }, 21500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#fun3").animate({ opacity: "0", }, 500, function () {
                        $("#fun4").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);
                    });
                }, 31500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#fun4").animate({ opacity: "0", }, 500, function () {
                        $("#fun1").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);
                    });
                }, 41500);
            }
            solve();
            setInterval(function () { solve(); }, 41520);

            //Work Counting functions

        }

        function startWork() {
            h = 1;
            m = 0;
            s = 0;
            document.getElementById("WTM").innerHTML = "01:00:00"
            inter = setInterval(function () { countWork() }, 1000);
        }

        function countWork() {
            if (s == 0 && m == 0 && h == 0) {
                $("#StartW").animate({ opacity: 1, }, 500);
                clearInterval(inter);
            }
            else if (s == 0 && m == 0 && h != 0) {
                h = h - 1;
                m = 59;
                s = 59;
            }
            else if (s == 0 && m != 0) {
                m = m - 1;
                s = 59;
            }
            else if (s != 0)
            { s = s - 1; }
            if (typeof (s) != "string" && s < 10)
            { s = "0" + s; }
            if (typeof (m) != "string" && m < 10)
            { m = "0" + m; }
            if (typeof (h) != "string" && h < 10)
            { h = "0" + h; }
            output = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            document.getElementById("WTM").innerHTML = output;
        }

        //Rest Counting functions

        function startRest() {
            h1 = 0;
            m1 = 10;
            s1 = 0;
            document.getElementById("RTM").innerHTML = "00:10:00";
            inter1 = setInterval(function () { countRest() }, 1000);
        }

        function countRest() {
            if (s1 == 0 && m1 == 0 && h1 == 0) {
                $("#StartR").animate({ opacity: 1, }, 500);
                clearInterval(inter1);
            }
            else if (s1 == 0 && m1 == 0 && h1 != 0) {
                h1 = h1 - 1;
                m1 = 59;
                s1 = 59;
            }
            else if (s1 == 0 && m1 != 0) {
                m1 = m1 - 1;
                s1 = 59;
            }
            else if (s1 != 0)
            { s1 = s1 - 1; }

            if (typeof (s1) != "string" && s1 < 10)
            { s1 = "0" + s1; }
            if (typeof (m1) != "string" && m1 < 10)
            { m1 = "0" + m1; }
            if (typeof (h1) != "string" && h1 < 10)
            { h1 = "0" + h1; }
            output1 = h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + s1;
            document.getElementById("RTM").innerHTML = output1;
        }

        //Calling the needed functions

        $("#StopW").click(function () {
            clearInterval(inter);
            document.getElementById("WTM").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
            $("#StartW").animate({ opacity: 1, }, 500);
        });

        $("#StartW").click(function () {
            startWork();
            $("#StartW").animate({ opacity: 0, }, 2000);
        });


        $("#StopR").click(function () {
            clearInterval(inter1);
            document.getElementById("RTM").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
            $("#StartR").animate({ opacity: 1, }, 500);

        });

        $("#StartR").click(function () {
            startRest();
            $("#StartR").animate({ opacity: 0, }, 2000);
        });

        facts();

    });
};

app.start();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using jQuery. Make sure you're using [jQuery 2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) and serving it locally from your app package.

The specific error you're seeing is likely the result of using `innerHTML` to set the countdown timers. Because apps run with elevated privileges (potential access to user files, etc), your code must not do things that may introduce vulnerabilities. `innerHTML` can be used to dynamically load scripts and thus it's use is discouraged.

In your application it looks like you could easily use `innerText` instead. If you must use innerHTML, try using `toStaticHTML(`) or wrapping it in `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction()`. You can read  more about [developing secure apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849625.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

don't use the VS2013 Previews any longer. The RTM is already out. Get the final Version here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-express